# How do I use UISegmentedControl to change the labels in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am a beginner to Swift so please bear with me.

Here is the documentation for using UISegmentedControl:

[Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruN6X.png)

Every single time I try using that code I get compilation code. I am currently trying to get the code to change segmentation 3 (custom) to whatever the user inputs (so a string).

I have tried:

```
func setTitle(_ title: "Hello"?,
forSegmentAtIndex segment: 3)
```

and

```
func setTitle(_ title: Hello?,
forSegmentAtIndex segment: 3)
```

and

```
func setTitle(_ title: "Hello"?,
forSegmentAtIndex segment: Int 3)
```

No idea how to correctly do this, please help!

Also, here's a link to the app i'm trying to make: http://i.imgur.com/CWoBkHk.gif. I just really want the custom button to reflect what the customized tip % is.

Comment: You have to call `setTitle:forSegmentAtIndex:` on an instance of a segmented control. If you don't know what that means then I suggest you find a good Swift tutorial and learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:-

Assuming you have outlet :-

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmented :UISegmentedControl?

//Now for changing the title:-
segmented?.setTitle("test1", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
segmented?.setTitle("test2", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
```